# S3 bucket alias

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a S3 bucket called "abcd" that I would like to map to a subdomain, "abcd.mydomain.com", using a CNAME.

Unfortunately I can't move files from the original "abcd" bucket to a new "abcd.mydomain.com" bucket, because it will break an existing iOs application.

My question is: is it possible to create an "abcd.mydomain.com" bucket and tell S3 that this new bucket is simply an alias to the original "abcd" bucket?

Comment: Have you found a way to do that? I'm in the exact same situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible with S3 directly. You can only use 1 subdomain with an S3 bucket.Also alias for bucket also not possible.